# Angular 2 Trying to wait until the subscribe finished Before executing code

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to change a variable's content inside the subscribe function

```
test : string="before";
this.peopleService.fetchRandom()
   .subscribe(person => {
       this.person = person;
       this.test = "after";
 });
        console.log(this.test);
```

as you can see the variable in question is test
and it is set to contain "after" inside lambda function.
Right now console log shows "before",
I wonder if there is a way for the code after subscribing to wait until the subscribe finished.

hopefully showing "after" in the console.log.

```
//this function is in the service 
fetchRandom(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._backendURL.randomPeople);
    }
```

a lot of answers to similar questions use async-await 
but in my context, it is not what I need.

Comment: No, there is no way. Put that code **inside** the callback, and it will execute at the right time, displaying the value you expect; "after".

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for your answear.
yes it is the solution i implemented but it does not feel, well elegent.
if i have alot of treatment to do inside or other functions to call etc.. 
it will inflate the subscribe function.

Comment: Well, put all that code inside a separate method, and call that separate method from inside the callback.